The vector space duality functor from Erdman's Elements of Linear and Multilinear Algebra
In Example 3.2.9 of Elements of Linear and Multilinear Algebra by John Erdman , given a linear map $T \in {\cal L}(V,W)$ where $V, W$ are vector spaces over a field $\mathbb{F}$, the pair of maps $V \mapsto V^*$ and $T \mapsto T^*$ define a contravariant functor "from the category of vector spaces and linear maps into itself" ($T^*$ is the adjoint defined as $T^* \in {\cal L}(W^*,V^*)$ where $V^*, W^*$ are the dual spaces of respectively $V, W$).
Earlier a contravariant functor is defined as an object map which associates each object $S$ in category ${\bf A}$ an object $F(S)$ in category ${\bf B}$ and a morphism map (also denoted by $F$) that associates with each morphism $f \in {\sf Mor}(S,T)$ in $\bf A$ a morphism $F(f) \in {\sf Mor}(F(T),F(S))$ in $\bf B$.
In this example vector spaces and linear maps are the two categories. The morphism map takes a linear map $T \in {\cal L}(V,W)$ to a linear map
$$F(T) \in {\cal L}(F(W),F(V)) \iff T^* \in {\cal L}(W^*,V^*).$$
I have two questions:

What is the object map in this case? I cannot see any meaningful map from vector spaces to linear maps.
In which way the duality functor (or any functor) "maps into itself"?



The object map takes $V$ to $V^{\ast}$. There is no map from vector spaces to linear maps involved. 2) "Itself" refers to the category of vector spaces. The source and target of the functor are both the category of vector spaces.


@QiaochuYuan if there is no map from vector spaces to linear maps, doesn't this contradict the author's definition of the object map ("associates with each object $S$ in $\bf A$ an object $F(S)$ in $\bf B$").

I don't understand what you mean. The definition says it associates with an object another object. Here you take the object $V$ and you get the object $V^{\ast}$. So that's fine. The words "linear map" or "morphism" appear nowhere in that definition.

The key thing to see is that it's not two different categories, it's just one category with two types of stuff in it. Let's denote the category by $\mathbf{Vect}_{\mathbb{F}}$.

The objects in $\mathbf{Vect}_{\mathbb{F}}$ are vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}$.
The arrows (morphisms) in $\mathbf{Vect}_{\mathbb{F}}$ are $\mathbb{F}$-linear maps between the vector spaces.

The duality functor $(-)^*$ maps objects in $\mathbf{Vect}_{\mathbb{F}}$ to other objects in $\mathbf{Vect}_{\mathbb{F}}$ (this is the "object map" part of the functor) and it also maps arrows in $\mathbf{Vect}_{\mathbb{F}}$ to other arrows in $\mathbf{Vect}_{\mathbb{F}}$ (this is the "morphism map" part). We can write the functor as
$$(-)^*:\mathbf{Vect}_{\mathbb{F}}\to\mathbf{Vect}_{\mathbb{F}}$$
This is the sense in which the functor maps $\mathbf{Vect}_{\mathbb{F}}$ "into itself".
As @Qiaochu noted in the comments, the functor maps a vector space $V$ to its dual space $V^*$. That's the action on objects. The functor also maps a linear map $V\to W$ to its dual map $W^*\to V^*$. That's the action on arrows. These two actions are separate but related things.

This makes sense. The definition in the book I referenced states that a functor is a map between categories ( objects->objects and morphisms-> morphisms). In this case the “categories” are vector spaces and dual spaces so thinking like this it is consistent.

@TedBlack No, dual spaces are vector spaces (objects) in the same category, as indicated in my answer.
